# False Virtue and True Virtue

Tags: ethics, virtue

Does any Buddhist school teach about False (fake, hypocritical) Virtue (goodwill, goodness)?

What it is, how common it is, how it differs from the true authentic virtue, perhaps its causes and its results - those kinds of things.

Is virtue in Buddhism *objective*, so that we can speak about true authentic virtue as something definite and timeless, or is all virtue always necessarily subjective and partial? Or perhaps there are two kinds of virtue, mundane virtue - partial and subjective - and supramundane virtue of non-attachment and non-identification?

If so, is there continuity and/or a single principle in common between both the worldly virtue and the supramundane virtue, so that we could simultaneously behave in line with both, or does behaving in line with supramundane virtue require going against or leaving behind the worldly virtue?

Is the authentic virtue something we can side with, against both *the vice* and *the false virtue* or is it something that requires going beyond the dichotomy and accepting all virtues and vices (or rejecting all virtues and vices)?

Basically, can we side with the Virtue&Truth in opposition to Vice&Hypocrisy, or is juxtaposing the two a wrong way to look at it, according to Buddhism?

What do the Pali Canon, the commentaries, and the Mahayana texts and commentaries teach about all this, if anything?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong view is wrong, meaning ingratitude and deny of more Sublime, lack of metta and not respecting fathers, leaders, gods. Taking side and home/stand, is wrong. All cause by sensual desire and craving for unwise identification. Not asking and listening to the Samanas and Brahmans of Noble domain.

Wrong action is wrong: taking existance, banner, destroy, deprive from dwelling. Taking what isn't given (and give with binding strings toward homes), is wrong. Abusing and unification with others outwardly ones traditional relation, "sex" for gain, is wrong. Not speaking truth, but biased by ones desires is wrong. Consume of what makes shameless, what leads to revolt, is wrong.

May good householder lay down side taking and seek by right ways, right conduct, not to fall into hell for another time. Kamma has effects, yet new must not be made and old fades when wrong doing is abound.

False and wrong can only be avoided by striktly stick to simple rules, for the uneducated mind isn't able to see through the net, is used to hold on what isn't real and easy misleaded by Mara and his host, google, facebook, exchange... having become slave of them.

The fake colors of the evil Tibetan sect, once adopted, are sure to become ones heading downwardly. One should not follow any sozial nationalism. NS is always cause of fear and not supported by wise and peaceful.

As soon as taking a stand in neutrality, turn toward right and Dhamma, conflicts will as quick disappear as quick they had been arosen.

Comment: Yes, right view: there is mother, father, this, next world, effects of good and bad deeds and those knowing of what they tell, others than on-householder. Don't suffer already enough? "We" isn't valide, but another social nationalism. The wise.

Comment: The try it, if possible gained faith. And stop talking without leaving, good householder. Wrong view gives wrong Sila...

Comment: Not even the Buddha could prevent even his relatives from ripping kamma. He simply left fools.

Comment: If Asuras and Devas are willing to come into the Domain of the Khema, ask, seek advice, of course they could receive the Dhamma, but they wouldn't. Like householder isn't willing, prefers to suffer further. Nobody can help you.

Comment: Try to gain peace for yourself. That's my persons and the Buddhas advice, for one not free from sensual desire and craving after home/stand, is incapable to help others. Get your own desires under control => Silas based on metta, right view (gratitude).

Comment: Fool, why victim blaming after wrong doing, instead of simply stopping.

Comment: Then, do your work to get out of the mud by leaving home/stand (the 6 senses, beginning with the five, world).

Comment: Everybody can leave home. Of course, if outwardly bond, might not live confortable (but thats old kamma, one has to bear)

Comment: And change your foolish user-name, stop encouraging toward harm. Asuras are as foolish as Devas, if wrong view. Side with the snake or the rat?

Answer (score -1):

DN 31 says to be free from the four types of *prejudice* or *bias* (*agati*), namely, prejudice due to (i) love; (ii) hate; (iii) fear & (iv) foolishness (idiocy, stupidity, absurdity, ignorance, lunacy, nonsense, silliness, asininity, absurdity, cretinousness, daftness, half-wittedness, inaneness, moronicness, etc).

SN 55.7 is about the Golden Rule (not doing to others that which you don't want done to you) and says to not only practice virtue but to speak in praise of the practice of virtue.

MN 8 says to not engage hypocrisy.

DN 31 refers to false friends & true friends. A false friend:

> (1) he who appropriates a friend's possessions, (2) he who renders
> lip-service, (3) he who flatters, (4) he who brings ruin. (i) he
> appropriates his friend's wealth, (ii) he gives little and asks much,
> (iii) he does his duty out of fear, (iv) he associates for his own
> advantage. (i) he makes friendly profession as regards the past, (ii)
> he makes friendly profession as regards the future, (iii) he tries to
> gain one's favor by empty words, (iv) when opportunity for service has
> arisen, he expresses his inability. (i) he approves of his friend's
> evil deeds, (ii) he disapproves his friend's good deeds, (iii) he
> praises him in his presence, (iv) he speaks ill of him in his absence.

As a worldly example, currently, there is a military operation in Ukraine to demilitarize Ukraine; similar to 1961 Cuban Missile Crisis. Sure, it sounds rather contradictory to use military to demilitarize. Ukraine is a weak country but the false friends offer to sell it weapons so its own people can be killed as geo-political pawns and then blame the bigger neighbor who felt threatened by the false friend of the prodigal little brother. This situation appears so prejudiced I heard in the 1st time its modern history, Switzerland is not taking a neutral position on a war conflict.

But, to answer this question, false or fake or Mara virtue is to only be virtuous under the power of prejudice (*agati*). For example, you change your user name to "I Hate Hitler" when Hitler invades Poland but you don't change your user name to "I Hate Bush, Obama, Trump, Biden" etc, when these individual invade Iraq, Libya, Syria, etc. Worse, you immigrate from a country that saved Syria to the country that invades, bombs and currently practises scorched earth policy in Syria. Like European Protestants who imagine Jesus had golden hair, blue eyes & white European features, you think the Buddha supports Western Hegemony & Woke Cultural Marxism.

In summary, the metta is not universal. The metta or virtue is tribal rather than Buddhist. One becomes a clown instead of enlightened. One holds hypocritical double standards. One claims to be against militarism but, in reality, are in favour of militarism. For 8 years, the user-name didn't change, despite all of the wars in the world, including in Eastern Ukraine where an estimated 14,000 people were killed since 2014. Instead of following Buddha-Dhamma, we follow the MSM. We support those who make countless wars around the world but when these warmakers are halted we come to their defense, claiming we are against war. We even claim Ukraine was against the Holocaust and Russia was for the Holocaust. It becomes this insane & crazy when there is no universal metta and only MSM imperialist prejudice (*agati*)

[image]

Comment: When I used to quarrel with my little brother, and my mum intervened, we'd tell her, "But he started it!" -- and she'd reply, "I don't care who started it: you both have to stop."

Comment: sounds wise but who is the Mum in this case?

Comment: I mentioned earlier, I think it's the doctrine that's important (and benefits everyone). And the question of whose doctrine it is, or whose is better, or which person has which role, or is superior, is part of the dispute (the "conceit"). So I think it's always (and maybe ever only) important to assess doctrine and to see how it informs you (and not try to use it to like, "criticise heretics"). Like I said I think it's "wise" to criticize (or to try to stop) bad behaviour, hopefully people can relate to that, that's instead of (as a matter of intention and of expression) criticizing people.

Comment: I think it's part of the genius of the dhamma and of how it's taught -- *... paccattaṃ veditabbo viññūhī ti.* -- it's offered in a way or manner that people can take (needn't reject, maybe the speech isn't "harsh") and adopt.